# Problema al comparar contraseñas con SHA

Tags: php, mysql

He diseñado un login en el cual le solicito al usuario, el nombre de usuario y la contraseña, tengo en mi base de datos una tabla 'Usuario' en el cual comparo los datos ingresados con los de la tabla, este código desempeña esta función.

```
 <?php


  $nomusuario = $_POST['usuario'];
  $pass = $_POST['contra'];





  $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","consultorioclinico") or    die ("Error en la conexión con la Base de Datos");

   $consulta = "Select * from usuario where NombreUsuario  =".$nomusuario."and Password =".sha($pass);


$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);


$row = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($row>0) {

if ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

    if ($fila['Rol']=="Administrador") {

        header("location:doctor.php");


    }
}
  }
  else{
echo "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos";

  }

 mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Esta es mi tabla "usuario"

[image]

He encriptado las contraseñas de la tabla con "SHA", y al intentar iniciar sesión la contraseña que se ingreso, no coincide con la encriptada en la tabla.

Específicamente en esta línea de código:

```
$consulta = "Select * from usuario where NombreUsuario =".$nomusuario."and     Password =".sha($pass);
```

Intento que la contraseña ingresada en el login coincida con la de la tabla (la cual esta encriptada) pero no me funciona y lo que quiero es que ambas coincidan y así poder ingresar al sistema.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92436/discussion-on-question-by-sasori1264-problema-al-comparar-contrasenas-con-sha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanto el nombre de usuario como el password son de tipo caracter en la base de datos.
Debes ingresarlos con comillas. Ejemplo

```
$consulta = "Select * from usuario where NombreUsuario ='".$nomusuario."' and     Password ='".$pass."'";  la encriptacion sha, tambien puedes hacerla cuando recibes el...
$pass = sha($_POST["password"])
```